# flush using tkinter, text output slowly

Tags: python, tkinter

i was wondering if it would be possible to output text slowly using tkinter and a label

the main problem is I don't know how to get it to flush. I press the button, and then it waits 9 seconds, then it prints the whole thing.

How do i get this to work with a flush
i've tried label1.flush(), but it gives me an error
also sys.stdout.flush() does't work, but it makes sense because this is to the console

```
def clicked():
    txt = "hello world"
    a = txt[0]
    label1 = tk.Label(window,text=a)
    label1.place(x=60,y=30)
    time.sleep(9)
    b = txt[1]
    c = a+b
    label1 = tk.Label(window,text=c)
    label1.place(x=60,y=30)
```

Comment: why do You think it waits for 9 seconds? could it be that You have put `time.sleep(9)` in that function that makes the whole script sleep for 9 seconds? also [edit] Your indentation

Comment: thats the point, I want it to first print the first character, and then 9 secs later print the next character. what it is doing so far is waiting 9 secs and the pushing out all the characters at once

Comment: is this the whole code? because I don't see how this would even print the whole text, also those nine seconds simply freeze the whole thread, nothing is gonna happen in those 9 seconds in that thread, sleep is not that great to use in the same thread as tkinter also there is no need to create another label and place it

Comment: its just the definition of the button press input, i didn't think it would be necessary to put the entire code into the script.

Comment: the only time You mention `flush()` method is in the 3rd paragraph. To answer that: `label1.flush()` throws an error probably because `label1` does not have a method called `flush()`, could be similar with the `sys.stdout`

Comment: no, You don't need to put the whole code, just a [mre].

Comment: sorry i new to python. i just have another label, cause I wanted to created a new string to print. I'm basically treating it like a print statement. anyways that's not my problem, everything works but using the sleep, would you know of another way to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `time.sleep` with tkinter as it blocks the GUI processing. This causes it to print the whole thing in one go. Flushing is not possible because this is a Tkinter GUI, not a console, so there is no stdout to flush. Instead, you have to do something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk

def clicked():
    n = 0
    txt = "hello world"
    showChar(n, txt)

def showChar(n, txt):
    n += 1
    label.config(text = txt[:n])
    if n < len(txt):
        root.after(9000, lambda: showChar(n, txt))

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text = "")
label.pack()
button = tk.Button(root, text = "Start", command = clicked)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When the button is clicked, the counter is initialised (set to 0) and the text is set. Then `showChar` is called. This function increments the counter, then updates the label text to show an extra character. If the string hasn't been full displayed yet, it waits 9000ms (or 9 seconds) until it runs itself again, using the tkinter method `root.after`. This then works as you want it to.

Comment: thanks so much! the other guy was just nit picking at me. it was annoying.

Comment: btw if using `.after()` You could simply do this: `root.after(9000, showChar, n, text)` not use `lambda`, btw have You ever looked at PEP 8, because I suggest You do and start formatting Your Python code as it was inteded, otherwise, great code

Comment: I'm well aware of PEP 8, I just prefer camelCase.

Comment: @poopmiller If this answer helped you, please [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this using [`.after`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-after-method-in-tkinter/) loops:

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Label


def print_slow(widget: Label, text, delay: 'in miliseconds', index=1, start_index=0):
    widget.config(text=text[start_index: index])
    index += 1
    return root.after(delay, print_slow, widget, text, delay, index) if index <= len(text) else None


root = Tk()

label = Label(root, text='')
label.pack()

print_slow(label, 'hello world', 2000)

root.mainloop()
```

So pretty simple:
First import only what You need, don't use wildcard (`*`)

Second define the function, it will take arguments such as the widget to which it is needed to print slowly, then the text that has to be printed, then delay in milliseconds between characters appearing on the screen, then the end index and start index.

Then simple tkinter stuff:
`.config()` the widget's text attribute to the text from `start_index` to the end `index`
Then increment the end `index` by one
Then use `.after()` to schedule the same function (loop) after the given `delay` and pass the incremented `index` argument

Then the simple `tkinter` stuff and also remember to initially call the function

EDIT: updated the function to actually stop when finished, used some ternary conditions to `return None` (basically stop in this case) if the `index` is bigger than the lenght of the text

Comment: @poopmiller You could mark the answer as correct, not mine obviously since I indeed was a bit annoying at the beginning (tho if You wish...), so mark the other guy's (@Henry) answer as correct (it also is basically the same as mine), he will probably appreciate it, don't forget to upvote it too